# How to get rolling 12 month sum in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have to create sum of 12 month sales from last month of my date column.

I have 3 years, 2016 to 2018 with Month and Year format and my dashboard is refreshed monthly adding next month.

If the last date is oct 2018,

I want to display 
2018 as sum of sales from oct 18 - oct 17
2017 as sum of sales from oct 17 to oct 16
2016 as sum of sales from oct 16 to oct 15 and so on.

Can you help how can i create the dax measure in power BI

If I am using 
= Calculate(sum(sales), dateadd(date, -12, month)
It is displaying only year wise (calculating oct18 to jan 18 only) and not giving me the result as mentioned above.

Can you help with the same?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a date/calendar table called 'Date', you can achieve a rolling 12 month sum using the following measure:

```
Rolling 12 Month Total :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[Sales] ),
    DATESBETWEEN (
        'Date'[Date],
        NEXTDAY ( SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( LASTDATE ( 'Date'[Date] ) ) ),
        LASTDATE ( 'Date'[Date] )
    )
)
```

Applying this to other years would just require you to change the bounds in the DATESBETWEEN function.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for first year.  I want to calculate for previous years using the same month as last date. Suppose of the last date is October 2018, this measure gave the sum from oct 18 - oct 17. I want to calculate for oct -17, oct 16 and so on. Is there any measure for that?

Comment: @CharithaBayapureddy can you send me some sample data?

Comment: How can I send the sample data?

Comment: you can post a sample here

Comment: Date Sales
Sep-17 10
Aug-17 20
Jan-17 30
Nov-16 50
Oct-16 80
Sep-16 130
Aug-16 210
Jan-16 340
Nov-15 550
Oct-15 890
Sep-15 1440
Aug-15 2330
Jan-15 3770
Nov-14 6100
Oct-14 9870
I want to calculate  sum for 12 months starting from latest date. i.e - Sept 17 to oct 16 and sept 16 to oct 15 and so on
2017 190
2016 2210
2015 23510

Answer (score -1):

be carefull with February you will have an isue. when the last day of current year is 28th and previous year is 29th.

The right formula is Rolling 12 Month

```
Total :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[Sales] ),
    DATESBETWEEN (
        'Date'[Date],
         SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( NEXTDATY(LASTDATE ( 'Date'[Date] ) ) ),
        LASTDATE ( 'Date'[Date] )
    )
)
```